# Open-source private keys management system

Tags: open-source, encryption, ssh, collection-manager

I use many virtual machines on my laptop.

I started pushing my code to bitbucket very often from different virtual machines. So I'm forced to geneterate/copy private/public key almost on every machine I use.

Again I need to generete key pair if I use another laptop.

Finally, I have dozen of keys and do not know their location.

Is there any open-source private keys management system?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially: 1) what OS must it run on? 2) what features must it have? 3) I suppose it should be some kind of "distributed" system so all the VMs can access it? Doesn't help to have the keys on machine A only when you need them on B,C,D... ;)

Comment: You don't need to generate new keys for every laptop - you can reuse the same keys on as many machines as you like (which you'd be doing anyways if, for example, you'd have the same homedir NFS-shared across multiple machines). The keys are identifying the user, not the machine. Just pay attention to preserve content and permissions of the files when you copy them from one place to another. And secure them in transit if copying them over non-trusted networks.

Comment: @DanCornilescu That's not a good idea. If your laptop gets stolen, your sole key is compromised and you need to change it on all devices. You should have one private key per domain, so a laptop has its own but machines with a shared home directory, or even inside the same premises, share one. For VMs on the same host, it depends whether they're for isolation (→ separate keys in case one is breached) or to run multiple OSes (→ same key copied from the host) — though most of the time you don't need any private key in a VM, just rely on agent forwarding.

Comment: If a private key (your sole one or one of many) is no longer private for whatever reason you still need to go to all your .ssh dirs and remove the corresponding public key from the authorized_keys file to properly close the security hole. Roughly the same amount of work I'd say.

Comment: I still have no idea what a "private keys management system" might be. Do you want something that returns you all your private keys from a single master key à la password manager? If so, I doubt that makes sense.